# Show warnings for Parsley 2.0-rc2?

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

Im using Parsley 2.0 and remote extension.

```
<input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" required="required" name="name" data-parsley-remote="/duplicate" data-parsley-remote-message="Oh shit! We already have it in the database!">
```

Most of our users cannot add duplicates but we have some admins that can add duplicates.
I want to display the duplicate message as warning but not prevent the form submission for Admin. 
So how do I show this warning?

Comment: It seems Parsley do not support warnings. You have to solve them by yourself (as I did).